# Objective-C using NSRunningApplication terminate, to quit iTunes

Tags: objective-c, itunes, terminate

I want to quit iTunes from my app, this is the code i have so far, but i get the error NSRunningApplication -undeclared.

```
if ([closeiTunes state] == NSOnState) {
    [[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.iTunes"] objectAtIndex:0] terminate];
}
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSRunningApplication` is a class that is only available in the 10.6 SDK. Set the Base SDK to Mac OS X 10.6 and there should be no problems.

Comment: When it says it requires the 10.6 SDK, that means 10.6 or OVER, so yes.